# how to serialize phpseclib?

Tags: php, serialization, phpseclib

I have been trying to serialize  phpseclib connection  since I am loading some php pages from ajax and I dont want to reconnect again and again.

**Page 1 - define SSH2 First**

```
require("Net/SSH2.php");
session_start();
$ssh = new Net_SSH2 ("localhost");
if ($ssh->login($username, $pass)) {
$_SESSION['obj'] = serialize($ssh);

}else{
echo "Invalid Login !!!";
}
```

**Page 2 - Get Stored session with unserialize**

```
session_start();
require("Net/SSH2.php");
$ssh = unserialize($_SESSION['obj']);
echo $ssh->exec('ls');
```

I want to put Login information in `$_SESSION['obj']` too so Whenever I am on that php page i just `$ssh = unserialize($_SESSION['obj']);` and then `$ssh->exec('pwd')` ..

Is there work around or will I have to always connect/login to Net/SSH2.php whenever I am on that PHP page ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to have a persistent connection is to actually have a script constantly running which is keeping the connection open. Which means you have one script with a never ending `while (true) { ... }` loop which opens a connection once and keeps it. You then need to find a way to communicate with this script to make it execute commands. [AMQP](http://www.amqp.org), [ØMQ](http://zero.mq), [Gearman](http://gearman.org), sockets and similar techniques can be employed for that.

Comment: Which most servers do not allow... eventually most of them close it to avoid stale processes or processes locked in eternal loops.

Comment: What are my best options if I can configure server per my requirement ? I am making an intranet app ... for internal use

Comment: @django I'd recommend you look into a persistent script and Gearman.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Depending on which PHP version you have, you could try to declare a static variable for the ssh connection.</strike>

If phpseclib uses pfsockopen it might be able to reuse existing connections - but that is a longshot, and might require modification of the library.

But generally speaking you cannot do what you want in PHP. When the script is finished all open sockets are closed, as the executing process terminates.
You certainly can't store it in a session variable - as soon as the Net_SSH2 object goes out of scope it is destroyed.

Comment: A static variable is equally useless.

Comment: Good to know - I read somewhere that it would work after 5.3 but that was hearsay.

Comment: So my only shot is logging again and again .. right ?
If yes should it be a problem for server to keep logging so much.. ?

Comment: I'm afraid it seems to be so, yes. That's the problem with server-side scripting.

Comment: Shouldn't require too much modification - just replace the only fsockopen call in Net/SSH2.php with pfsockopen and you're done! No idea if it'd work though. I think persistent connections are somewhat server dependent.

Comment: That is quite correct, just as with mysql_pconnect the server must allow it.

Comment: @django Then I'm guessing that pfsockopen is not enabled/allowed in your PHP installation.

Comment: @fredrik
I Followed http://raman-kumar.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-can-we-enable-fsockopen-function-in.html and found that allow_url_fopen = On is already set to on in my php.ini and If i run test script from above link it returns connected.

Comment: Looking at code at question .. can anyone suggest how can i make a persistent script for phpseclib which i can run as daemon service may be ?