# PHP SSH2 save current session for repeatable commands

Tags: php, session, ssh, phpseclib

I want to simulate SSH commands via PHP

Currently i tried to use **phpseclib**:
http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/

The code is:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('184.170.248.68');

if (!$ssh->isConnected() && !$ssh->login('payton', 'lowe225')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
echo '<pre>';
echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
echo '</pre>';
```

Each time when i do request to script i must wait when authentication will be done.

Is there any way to store SSH session and restore it on second PHP script call, to make script run faster?

I know that better way is to develop server side application with API interface to do that in better way. But i want to know if in small task that can be achieved.

Comment: Seems like you're asking this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361748/how-to-serialize-phpseclib

Comment: Afraid that you are right. Basically all comes to server programming with API. And direct application is a better choice now.